# Do I have to update every cookies everytime?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using my `c#` app to send request to the webpage. Before I send any request I have to be logged in this webpage. I want to avoid logging everytime I want to do some work, so I am storing cookies in sql server database in `VARBINARY` column.

Lets say I am sending 50 `POST requests` every day:

```
 private string getRequest(string url, string postData = "")
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                StreamReader reader;
                var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14";
                request.CookieContainer = Cookie;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                postData = Uri.EscapeUriString(postData);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                Byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

                requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                foreach (Cookie tempCookie in response.Cookies)
                {
                    Cookie.Add(tempCookie);
                }
                reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string readerReadToEnd = reader.ReadToEnd();
                response.Close();

                database.updateCookie(AccountId, Cookie);  //here I am updating the cookies

                return readerReadToEnd;
            }
            catch { return ""; }
```

Do I really need to update `Cookies` after every request? Or maybe could I update my cookies only once, after sending 50 `POST requests`?

I am asking, because sometimes my cookies lasts couple days, and sometimes they died after 1 minute. I don't really know why and how to avoid that.

Do I have to store the newest verion of cookies or maybe can I use the same everytime?

Comment: That depends on what cookies the server sends.

Comment: Why do you need to store cookies in your database? Cookies belong on the clients machine, if you are storing them in the database too what is the point of storing on the clients machine?

Comment: @SeanLange because I restart my PC sometimes. I want to store cookies in database to avoid logging.

Comment: I don't understand that logic at all but whatever. If you want your database to reflect the current value of your cookies you will need to update your database every single time the cookie changes. Personally if I was going to store these values in the database I would do that and forget the cookies entirely. It seems totally pointless to me.

Comment: @SeanLange
I just want to run my c# application on virtual server 24h/day. My c# app need to be logged into a website (like you are logged in stackoverflow right now) whole time and I am wondering if is that possible. I want to know what to do to be logged all the time. Do I need to do request every 10,20 or 30 minutes to keep act like active user. Do I need to update my stored Cookies every time I do request. Can you give me any tips what would you do if you had to make for example auto response bot for stackoverflow. Bot would have to be logged in 24/7 to answer messages.

Answer (score 0):

Each site decides how long particular cookies are valid. Hence you need to get that information for each site individually to do it correctly. Paying attention to "expiration" on the cookie (in "set-cookie" headers of response) may give you initial guidance on when cookie is guaranteed to expire.

Common expiration/validity ranges:

- authentication cookies - from 10 minutes to 1 day
- ASP.Net session state - from 20 minutes
- CSRF protection - possibly updated on every response

Comment: Hmm but If I enter for example Stackoverflow 7 days later I am still logged. I want to do the same in my c# application. If I send another request for example after 3 days I want to be already logged in my c# app.

Comment: @Dawvawd "common" != "every single one"... Feel free to figure out how particular site handle authentication and hack away... Note that some sites provide proper API to access information from non-web apps - depending on your target sites it may be better approach than hoping to get cookies right when scraping.